# Space between cells in UITableView

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have UIViewController with UITableView.
In the table I have two different cells and use UITableViewAutomaticDimension.

- First and second cell - one style (no space between cells)
- Second and third cell - different styles (have some space as in image)

How can I remove this space?

P.S. Xib of cells are good.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can subclass UITableViewCell and add something like:

```
// Inside UITableViewCell subclass
override func layoutSubviews() {
super.layoutSubviews()

let frame = contentView.frame
let frameRect = UIEdgeInsetsInsetRect(frame, UIEdgeInsetsMake(5, 5, 5, 5))
contentView.frame = frameRect
```

}

Then based on the indexPath.row you can chose which tableView cell you want to use, like :

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell 
{
  let cell:UITableViewCell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: cellReuseIdentifier) as UITableViewCell!
  //First cell
  if(indexPath.row == 0)   {
     // Would need to return appropriate cell here
  }

if(indexPath.row == 1)   {
         // Would need to return appropriate cell here
      }

  return cell
}
```

Hope this helps.